# SAS: What are the difference between "data files" and "raw data files"?

Tags: import, sas, proc-sql, file-io

So, according to SAS books, you do:

```
PROC IMPORT
DATAFILE="filename" | TABLE="tablename"
OUT=SAS-data-set
<DBMS=identifier><REPLACE>;
```

for data files, and you use INFILE to read raw data files...

So what exactly is "raw data files"? Are CSV files data files or "raw data files"? Are space-separated text files data files or "raw data files"?

Answer (score 1):

I think "data files" might refer to SAS created data files, whereas "raw data files" refers to any other data file source (excel, csv, dat, etc). As I understand it (reading roughly from "The Little SAS Book" by Delwiche & Slaughter), `proc import` will scan your file (at least the first 20 rows) to automatically determine variable types and ideal lengths. `INFILE` is a more primitive in ways, but allows you to specify what variables to read through the `input` keyword. You can also do data manipulations directly within the `DATA` step where your `INFILE` is used, which cannot be done with `proc import` (at least I don't think it can). Check http://www.sfu.ca/sasdoc/sashtml/proc/z0332605.htm and http://support.sas.com/onlinedoc/913/getDoc/en/lrcon.hlp/a000998889.htm for additional info.

Comment: correct - the distinction is usually that 'data files' are SAS datasets, and 'raw data files' are external files of a variety of types such as .csv, .txt, .dat etc.